# Fancybox pop up opens automaticly after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I used fancy box pop up like that

```
 <div class="x-popup" id="PopUpWarning">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="info" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" height="175">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server" Text="You must choose less than 256 item in the following fields :"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadListView ID="lvWarningFields" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemTemplate">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemTemplate" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server"><%# Container.DataItem %></asp:Label>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadListView>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="bottom-buttons cf">
                <div class="fr">
                    <a href="#" class="button cancel">Cancel</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I open fancybox pop-up in button click event at code behind. like that

**c# side**

```
string jsWarning = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(showWarning);</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showWarning", jsWarning);
```

**aspx side**

```
function showWarning() {
            show_popup('PopUpWarning');
        };
```

I open pop up in button event. And click close button call $.fancybox.close(); and pop up closed. But after postback in same page Pop-up opens automaticly.

I guess I need to remove Sys.Application.add_load(showWarning); script? Is it true?

Why my pop up opens after postback. I need to open pop-up only button click fired. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any reason why you bind the javascript event to a push button in code behind? Things could be much much easier if you just add the appropriate onClick event on your aspx page. Do you care to elaborate on your implementation?

Comment: Because I use fancybox. And fancy box pop ups only open with js in that example 'show_popup' calls a function in fancybox.js . We cant open fancybox from server side. But I need to open fancybox pop up after some server side operations. So I need to call js from serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep below code in aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showWarning() {
        show_popup('PopUpWarning');
    };
</script>
```

Call the function from C# button click like below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showWarning", "showWarning();", true);
```

Comment: I tried this. It fixed my problem but another problem occured. When my pop-up opend I realize that pop-up shape is not well formed. Pop up lost its own shape?

Comment: it may due to css problem.

ok, first pull popup code into a plain html page with some data and run in the same browser which you ran your aspx page. fix issues if you found any.

Comment: Nothing changed. If I use tring jsWarning = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(showWarning);</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showWarning", jsWarning); pop-up open with own shape. But If I use criptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showWarning", "showWarning();", true); it lost its own shape

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showValidation", "$(function(){showValidation();});", true); fixed css problem. Thx Sunil.